# Python compare two columns of excel sheet as pair

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have workbook which contains 2 excel sheets. i want to compare two columns as pair of first excel sheet with 2 columns in a pair of second excel sheet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set operations are made easier by the introduction of pandasql. Check this out:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

df1 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'Sheet 1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'Sheet 2')


df_res = ps.sqldf("""select select case when df2.col1 is null 
                      then 'no match' 
                      else 'they match' end as do_they_match
                     from df1
                      left join df2
                       on df1.col1 = df2.col1
                        and df1.col2 = df2.col2 """, locals())
```

Comment: @zaman-azam: If this solution worked for you, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below approach to add the first two columns in each (if they're strings they'll concatenate) and then compare values in each. This would require they be the same length, and this assumes you want to compare based on position, not inclusion (in which case you could just merge on those two columns to see what matches).

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'Sheet 1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'Sheet 2')

df1.iloc[:,0] + df1.iloc[:,1] == df2.iloc[:,0] + df2.iloc[:,1]
```